# Thread being Aborted while inserting data using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Below is my code where I'm trying to inserts logs into database using Entity Framework. As you can see that I'm using an asynchronous delegate to do so. The thing is that this code resides inside a class library and the connection string info and whatever Nuget packages have added  when I added Entity Framework Oracle data access stuff into my code, sits in app.config file of this class library. Now when I add a reference to this .dll in my other project in the same solution though and try to execute asynchronous delegate to inserts logs into database I get thread being aborted exception, I tried everything possible that people (including adding a new app.config file in the project where I'm referring to this class library and putting in a connection string there as well) are telling over on stackoverflow and everywhere else. But still I'm not able to get rid of this exception.I have given  the entire stack call below my code.It throws the exception at the using statement inside SaveLogEntry(...) method.

```
   using (TracingEntity traceEntity = new TracingEntity())


  private void WriteLineInternal(string message, string category, string   componentName, string threadId,int windowsProcessId, string machineName, string exceptionThrown,string customMessage,int traceEventId, string processName, string userId)
    {
        loggingFunction = SaveLogEntry;
        IAsyncResult obj = loggingFunction.BeginInvoke(message, category, componentName, threadId, windowsProcessId,machineName, exceptionThrown,customMessage,traceEventId,processName, userId, null, null);
    }

    private void SaveLogEntry(string message, string catrgory, string componentName, string threadId, int windowsProcessId, string machineName, string exceptionThrown, string customMessage, int traceEventId, string processName, string userId)
    {
        lock (traceLockObject)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TracingEntity traceEntity = new TracingEntity())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApplicationName))
                    {
                        traceEntity.INSERTTRACELOGS(message, catrgory, componentName, threadId, windowsProcessId, machineName, processName, exceptionThrown, customMessage, traceEventId, null, userId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        traceEntity.INSERTTRACELOGS(message, catrgory, componentName, threadId, windowsProcessId, machineName, processName, exceptionThrown, customMessage, traceEventId, ApplicationName, userId);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (this.DBTraceFailed != null)
                {
                    DBTraceFailed(ex.ToString());
                }
                this.WriteEntryToInternalLog(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at LoggingAndTracingLib.TracingEntity..ctor() in C:\LOFT_Projects\LoggingAndTracingLib\LoggingAndTracingLib\TraceDBModel.Context.cs:line 21
   at LoggingAndTracingLib.CustomDBTraceListener.SaveLogEntry(String message, String catrgory, String componentName, String threadId, Int32 windowsProcessId, String machineName, String exceptionThrown, String customMessage, Int32 traceEventId, String processName, String userId) in C:\LOFT_Projects\LoggingAndTracingLib\LoggingAndTracingLib\CustomDBTraceListener.cs:line 483**

Comment: Can you give the inner exception details?

Comment: App.config has no effect for .dll. Copy the whole content (not only connection string) to the .exe app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have correctly set your connection string? Looks like the framework cannot find the right connection string inside your .config file or there are issues accessing the file itself.

Sometimes the thread abort exception can "hide" the real exception. Check the inner exception to have more details.